# If the Fourier transform of a probability measure goes to zero at infinity, can the measure have a point mass?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Is the following implication true?
$$
\widehat{\mu}(y) \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } |y| \rightarrow \infty \quad \Rightarrow \quad \mu(\{x\})=0 \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to these [notes](http://mypage.iu.edu/~rdlyons/pdf/seventy.pdf) (page 3), this was proved by Neder in 1920.
One can also use the criterion given by Wiener in 1924, reminded in the same notes.

This is about measures on the circle, but I believe there must not be a big difference with the case of the real line.

Comment: Cool notes.  I love some late night dst.

Comment: @nomen I have a feeling your comment is hilarious, but I need to know what a dst is to unlock the hilarity. :)

Comment: @Jason: Descriptive Set theory. :)

Comment: @Ahriman Thanks. I forgot these measures had a name.

Comment: @nomen Hilarity unlocked!!!

Comment: I thought it was referring to Daylight Saving Time. :)